# How to identify multiple ranges in a video/ image using Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I am working with an rgb image data, I need to analyze it using multiple ranges. So I choose range 1 which is the whole data range, range 2 which consists of 2 ranges each is half of the data range, range 3 consists of 4 ranges each is 1/4 of my data and so on.
I need a compact Matlab code that can accomplish that, my code so far is as follows:

```
% The raw data is a video sequence, it is stored into frames, and I'm working with 1 frame at a time.
% These ranges deal with the r component only
range_1=image_data(:,:,1,1);
%range 2
% for i=1:2
%     range2(:,:,:,i)=image_data(1:1:vidHeight,1+((i-1)*vidWidth/2):1:(i-1)*vidWidth,1,1);
% end
range_2_1=image_data(1:1:vidHeight,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_2_2=image_data(1:1:vidHeight,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
%range 3
range_3_1=image_data(1:1:vidHeight/2,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_3_2=image_data(1+vidHeight/2:1:vidHeight,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_3_3=image_data(1:1:vidHeight/2,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
range_3_4=image_data(1+vidHeight/2:1:vidHeight,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
%range 4

range_4_1=image_data(1:1:vidHeight/4,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_4_2=image_data(1+vidHeight/4:1:vidHeight/2,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_4_3=image_data(1+vidHeight/2:1:3*vidHeight/4,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_4_4=image_data(1+3*vidHeight/4:1:vidHeight,1:1:vidWidth/2,1,1);
range_4_5=image_data(1:1:vidHeight/4,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
range_4_6=image_data(1+vidHeight/4:1:vidHeight/2,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
range_4_7=image_data(1+vidHeight/2:1:3*vidHeight/4,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
range_4_8=image_data(1+3*vidHeight/4:1:vidHeight,1+vidWidth/2:1:vidWidth,1,1);
```

I need to perform this analysis for further ranges for all rgb data for all image frames, a total of 114. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mat2cell` does what you're looking for, I believe. You would call mat2cell with your frame data, and pass in the size of the submatrices you want to receive. So, for instance:

```
frame = rand(128,128);

range1 = frame;
range2 = mat2cell(frame,[64,64],[64,64]);
range3 = mat2cell(frame,[32,32,32,32],[32,32,32,32]);
```

etc. The second and third arguments are the widths and heights of each submatrix. The results will be stored in a cell array.

You could write a function which does this for you pretty easily. To get you started:

```
function ranges = range_fun(frame, num_ranges)
ranges1 = repmat(size(frame,1)/num_ranges,1,num_ranges);
ranges2 = repmat(size(frame,2)/num_ranges,1,num_ranges);

ranges = mat2cell(frame,ranges1,ranges2);
```

This needs work obviously, as it will crash if the frame cannot be evenly divided into whatever range you desire.